# Practical realization of a optical system for a laser

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, laser, geometric-optics, fiber-optics

I'm doing a pre-diploma thesis on how to build a laser system for the treatment of carbon nanotubes at my university. I'm relatively far into the whole project, we've already acquired a laser system (diode laser, 6W, 446 nm), the fitting fiber and a couple of lenses. I'm currently searching for a fitting fiber collimator.

I'm now at a point where I need to calculate the distances of the elements from each other, as well as how the beam changes while going through those elements. Although I have acquired a good foundation of knowlegde about how lasers, optics and fibers work, I can't seem to figure out, how to calculate the needed quantities because even though I have many books available, they usually are either leaving stuff out (like the quality factor k), don't go deep enough into the matter, only treat optics for things like microscopes or use information I don't have.

I'm now looking for some literature that helps me deal with the practical realization of such a system and I'm hoping you could name some books that deal with that kind of work.